# Flutter full Apple Pencil support

Tags: flutter, apple-pencil

I am working on a signature app in Flutter and I need full support of Apple Pencil.

Can I get full information about drawing with Apple Pencil? Such as angle, frequency, etc.

Currently I only get a point and pressure which is depends on points. I will be happy for any suggestions or tips :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: here's the issue on github https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38135